# How In Import Hex number into a Pandas Data Frame

Tags: pandas, pandasql

I am using Pandas 0.22.0, Numpy 1.14.0 with Python 3.6 and I am importing data from MS SQL, one of the fields holds an OID value of 0x537AA051BEBB01A2 when I read this in to a data frame in Pandas it converts it to b'Sz\xa0Q\xbe\xbb\x01\xa2' and then when I insert it into another MS SQL I get a bunch of weird characters.
I was wondering what I have to do to have this come in correctly and insert into another MS SQL database. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you share some code that is reading data into the pandas table. The problem seems to be the conversion of `0x537AA051BEBB01A2` to `b'Sz\xa0Q\xbe\xbb\x01\xa2'`. Also, please share the character encodings used by your MS SQL server

Comment: I am using pyodbc for my connection: connSource = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={{SQL Server}};SERVER={0};DATABASE={1};UID={2};PWD={3}".format(dbserver['server'],dbSource,dbUserSource,dbPasswordSource)) and then I load the data frame with df = pd.io.sql.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM Lot", connSource) and the OID field is a binaary(8)  and the MSSQL Database Collation is Latin1_General_BIN